# ImportError: No module named 'hypothesis'

Tags: python, import

I installed hypothesis on Anaconda with `conda install hypothesis`. I use Python 3.7 on Spyder.

In a file called `testing.py` I wrote

```
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st
```

but when I run the file, it says:

> ImportError: No module named 'hypothesis'

How can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: How are you running the code?  What exact command do you use?

Comment: This error comes out when I run the file (F5).

Comment: Have you tried to install this module with pip? I remember having a similar issue with `conda install` before.

Answer (score 2):

Install Hypothesis with Pip

```
pip install hypothesis
```

this will resolve the issue.

> Also, 0.2.2 is the best stable version confirmed by the developers.

Comment: When I try to install it with pip, it shows this:

(base) C:\Users\Jonathan Frassineti\Desktop>pip install hypothesis Requirement already satisfied: hypothesis in c:\users\jonathan frassineti\anaconda\lib\site-packages (4.36.2) Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=16.0.0 in c:\users\jonathan frassineti\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from hypothesis) (19.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have 2 versions of python installed and when you try to install with pip it installs in another place while you try to use it in another version.

Comment: How can I verify that?

Comment: I assume you already know the python version of conda, so go where you want to use pip, and try to find python version using "python -V" (uppercase V). check to see if those match. and try to use your IDLE and check the code.

Comment: Yeah, I found there are 2 versions of python, if I use the newest one Spyder recognize hypothesis luckily.

Comment: if you use windows, then you should check your environment variables, to see which version of python you use when you try pip.

Answer (score 0):

You're not in your project directory

```
   cd to your file
```

test by running test

```
   pytest
```

or

```
   python manage.py test
```